# PostgreSQL interval error

Tags: sql, postgresql

I run a query like this:

```
SELECT (SELECT expire_date FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10)
      - interval '1 mon 133 days 22:19:49.191748'
```

And everything is well.
But when I try this:

```
SELECT (SELECT expire_date FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10)
      - interval ((SELECT expire_date-now() FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10)
                 + interval '1 months')
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "("
LINE 1: ...FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10) - interval ((SELECT ex...
                                                             ^
```

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to compute?  Your subqueries (probably) aren't necessary.  The first "interval" keyword isn't necessary.  If I follow your parentheses, you appear to be computing `x - ((x - NOW) + '1 month')`, that is, 1 month ago whatever the value of `x`.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that Postgres [allows](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS-GENERIC) the `type 'string'` syntax for specifying the type for simple literal constants. For anything else you have to use `...::type` or `CAST ( ... AS type )`.

Comment: I tried SELECT (SELECT expire_date FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10) - interval ((SELECT expire_date-now() FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10 ) + interval '1 months')::character varying

but still get error

Comment: `SELECT (SELECT expire_date FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10) -  ((SELECT expire_date-now() FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10 ) + interval '1 months')::interval` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your first query is equivalent to:

```
SELECT expire_date - interval '1 mon 133 days 22:19:49.191748' as expire_date
FROM "License" 
WHERE license_id = 10
```

Second(though probably won't run):

```
SELECT expire_date - (expire_date-now() + interval '1 months') 
FROM "License" 
WHERE license_id = 10
```

So, better you write:

```
SELECT now() - interval '1 months'  
FROM "License" 
WHERE license_id = 10
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your second query is equivalent to this one. I could be wrong.

```
SELECT (SELECT expire_date 
        FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10) 

     - (SELECT expire_date - now() + interval '1 months' 
        FROM "License" WHERE license_id = 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify to:

```
SELECT expire_date - (expire_date - now()) - interval '1 month'
FROM   "License"
WHERE  license_id = 10
```

This is valid without *additional* brackets because subtractions are evaluated from left to right.
<sub>In my first version the one necessary pair of brackets was missing, though.</sub>

This form of the query also prevents an error in the case that `license` should not be unique. You would get multiple rows instead. In that case, and if you should need it, add `LIMIT 1` guarantee a single value.

---

@Milen diagnosed the cause of the error correctly. Experiment with these statements to see:

```
SELECT interval (interval '1 month');   -- error
SELECT (interval '1 month')::interval;  -- no error
```

However, the cure is simpler. Just don't add another cast, it is redundant.